# What does $X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb R $ mean?

Tags: real-analysis

$X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb R $(real numbers). I have been reading OK real analysis and have seen this a few times and do not really understand it.

Comment: It's a map from $X\times X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: And in the event that you don't know what $\times$ means, it is in this context a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), $A\times B = \{(a,b)~:~a\in A,b\in B\}$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  An example is a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol(?) $X \times X$ represents the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the set $X$ with itself. Thus, $X \times X = \{(x_0,x_1): x_0,x_1 \in X\}$. Whenever you see something like "$f: A \to B$," this is to be read as "$f$ is a function which takes elements in the set $A$ to elements in the set $B$."

Thus, $X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is the description of the domain/range pair of some function, which takes elements of the form $(x_1, x_2) \in X \times X$ and turns them into some real number.

As an example, suppose $X$ is the set of integers, and let $f: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x_1, x_2) = |x_1 - x_2|$. Then $f((1,5)) = |1-5| = |-4| = 4$.